# How can we flag question that belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I don't understand how to flag the question so it can migrate in other S.E. sites. It seems that when I flag it and I choose  "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" can be only be migrated to Chemistry meta. I think physics, biology, mathematics should be included.

Comment: I found [this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/882/how-to-migrate-questions-from-stackoverflow). I found that interesting and helpful.

Comment: @Martin yes but in fact unix have 5 sites we have only 1 site (meta), but we could have 5 I hope that someone notice this feature request and activate at least physics and biology...

Comment: Relevant *why* I marked this as declined: [Why are there no migrations paths to Physics.SE, Math.SE, etc.?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4202/4945) [Guidelines for closing as off-topic, belong on a different SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3963/4945)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't currently set up migration paths until after a site leaves the beta phase. The notion is that while in beta, a site's on- and off-topic lists will likely be in flux a bit. We don't want to set up migration paths and have content start flying around that was decided is off-topic, then maybe the community decides it was on-topic after all, etc. Additionally, migrations should be fairly rare, anyway; you should not only be sure that a particular question is off-topic for *your* site: you should be equally sure that it *is* **on-topic** for the destination site.

It doesn't hurt to think about which sites might someday be useful to have as migration paths from Chemistry.SE, but they won't be set up quite yet.