# Enable migration paths to Physics and Biology

Tags: feature-request, migration

According to an answer to [this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368/how-can-we-flag-question-that-belongs-on-another-site-in-the-stack-exchange-netw) question, now that Chemistry.SE is out of beta, it is eligible to have migration paths to other sites. I think paths to Physics.SE and Biology.SE would be very helpful now that this is possible.

Is this already in the works or is there somewhere we have to go to ask?

Comment: Not absolutely sure, but I'd like to find this out.

Comment: @jonsca what prompted me was [this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31560/how-clean-do-i-need-to-be-to-not-be-able-to-conduct-electricity). I feel like it belongs better on Physics.SE

Comment: I'm going to leave that for the time being, as I think it's somewhat okay here.  We *can* (and have been able to) migrate things by hand, but I'd like the community to have these options if they choose to use them.

Comment: We ask here. We haven't had _any_ non-meta migrations in the past 90 days so I doubt the team will give us these paths however.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I was looking at the stat page for meta. We have 3 (all successful) migrations to physics in the last 90 days. Not too much; so the request will still probably be rejected. No harm in keeping this request up; though!

Comment: It would be interesting to know if physics has a migration path to us, if they do, this might be another reason to have it here, too. On the other hand, three occurrences of migrations in about three month seems nothing that couldn't be handled manually. As far as I remember, I hardly ever voted to close on questions that belong to a different network page. There were a couple of borderline cases, which would have to be handled manually in any case. @Manish you are a mod on phy, can you find that out for us?

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Physics doesn't, though that's partially because Chem was beta and migration paths to beta aren't allowed. When we got a migration path to Math we had a much higher frequency of migration with very low rejection. I think Chem has a nontrivial rejection rate from Phys too, so I doubt a path of this type will be added to physics.

Comment: @ManishEarth I spoke with Shog who wanted to see some evidence of the community's need, expressed through a meta post.   Once we have a few more votes on this one, I think we can plead a case.

Comment: I just would like to state, that I recently saw, that biology has a custom off-topic message for chem.se, [example](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/30832). I don't really think, that it is necessary, but I still wanted to point that out.

Comment: I'd vote also for ability to propose move to Medicalsciences.SE, to handle questions about an allergy to water.

Answer (score 3):

> what prompted me was [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31560/how-clean-do-i-need-to-be-to-not-be-able-to-conduct-electricity). I feel like it belongs better on Physics.SE

If this is the kind of questions that users would vote for migration to Physics, then that's a reason *not* to enable user-driven migration there. Users are prone to vote for migration from X to Y when they find that the question is "more like Y than like X". On Math, they often suggest migrating Physics homework dumps to Physics, or personal agony stories to Academia. Neither is appropriate for the destination site.

Migration works when for questions that are written for the correct audience but posted on the wrong site: e.g., a good question about web browser use posted on Web Application, or a good mathematical question posted on Mathematica.

If, however, the question is something of Chemistry and something of Physics... then I'd guess that it's either too broad, too vague, or (best case) should to be rewritten by the author to properly address the audience of physicists. Migration can't fix any of that.

(No opinion on the path to Biology, which is still in beta. I think these two potential paths should be discussed separately.)